# What will be the graph of the straight line Arg (z-a)= $\pi$ + $\theta$.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

I am not able of gaining proper geometry of the above equation, where a=m+ $\iota$ n,  where m & n both are positive.

Comment: What do you mean by the geometry of a line? Please make your question more concrete.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience. I don't know how to make it more concrete . Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The number $a\in \mathbb{C}$ represents a point $A$ in the first quadrant, and we are looking for the points $M(z)$  where $z$ verifies $Arg(z-a)=\pi+\theta.$

In other words, the oriented angle of vectors $\vec{OA}$ and $\vec{OM}$ has the measure $\pi+\theta.$ Therefore, the set of points $M$ is the open half-line starting at $O$ that creates an angle $\pi+\theta$ (or, better, $-\theta$) with the half line $OA.$

Comment: Yes. Thankuh so much.